# .Net DefaultValueAttribute on Properties

Tags: c#, .net

I got this code in a user control:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Red")]
public Color MyColor { get; set; }
```

How can I change `MyColor` to be its default value?

Comment: In VS2015 - [C# 6](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6/) feature: `public bool MyColor { get; set; } = Color.Red;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is informal, but you can use it via reflection, for example, place in your constructor the following:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo p in this.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    foreach (Attribute attr in p.GetCustomAttributes(true))
    {
        if (attr is DefaultValueAttribute)
        {
            DefaultValueAttribute dv = (DefaultValueAttribute)attr;
            p.SetValue(this, dv.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the example given, the attribute is set against the property, not the field.

Comment: Ok, so - rewrite - 
foreach (FieldInfo f in this.GetType().GetFields())
as 
foreach (PropertyInfo f in this.GetType().GetProperties())

Comment: Wait wtf? Why is this accepted? If this answers your question, you need to rewrite your question.

Answer (score 21):

The `DefaultValueAttribute` does not set the property to the value, it is purely informational. The Visual Studio designer will display this value as non-bold and other values as bold (changed), but you'll still have to set the property to the value in the constructor.

The designer will generate code for the property if the value was set by the user, but you can remove that code by right clicking on the property and clicking `Reset`.

Answer (score 11):

`DefaultValueAttribute` is not used by the compiler, and (perhaps confusingly) it doesn't set the initial value. You need to do this your self in the constructor. Places that *do* use `DefaultValueAttribute` include:

- `PropertyDescriptor` - provides `ShouldSerializeValue` (used by `PropertyGrid` etc)
- `XmlSerializer` / `DataContractSerializer` / etc (serialization frameworks) - for deciding whether it needs to be included

Instead, add a constructor:

```
public MyType() {
  MyColor = Color.Red;
}
```

(if it is a `struct` with a custom constructor, you need to call `:base()` first)

Answer (score 4):

The "DefaultValue" attribute does not write code for you... but rather it is used for you to tell people (such as Mr Property Grid, or Mr Serializer Guy) that *you* plan to set the default value to Red.

This is useful for things like the PropertyGrid... as it will *BOLD* any color other than Red... also for serialization, people may choose to omit sending that value, because you informed them that it's the default :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you initializing `MyColor` in your constructor?

The `DefaultValue` attribute does not actually set any values. It simply instructs the designer for which value to not generate code and will also show the default value non-bold to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I adapted the answer of Yossarian:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo f in this.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    foreach (Attribute attr in f.GetCustomAttributes(true))
    {
        if (attr is DefaultValueAttribute)
        {
            DefaultValueAttribute dv = (DefaultValueAttribute)attr;
            f.SetValue(this, dv.Value, null);
        }
    }
}
```