# DefaultValue attribute is not working with my Auto Property

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, default-value, automatic-properties

I have the following Auto Property

```
[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool RetrieveAllInfo { get; set; }
```

when I try to use it inside the code i find the default false for is `false` I assume this is the default value to a `bool` variable, does anyone have a clue what is wrong!?

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705553/net-defaultvalueattribute-on-properties). In VS2015: `public bool RetrieveAllInfo { get; set; } = true;` It's [C# 6](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6/) feature.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The DefaultValue attribute is only used to tell the Visual Studio Designers (for example when designing a form) what the default value of a property is. It doesn't set the actual default value of the attribute in code.

More info here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311339

Comment: Thank you Philippe, so I think the only solution is from the constructor. thanks

Answer (score 18):

`[DefaultValue]` is only used by (for example) serialization APIs (like `XmlSerializer`), and some UI elements (like `PropertyGrid`). It doesn't set the value itself; you must use a constructor for that:

```
public MyType()
{
    RetrieveAllInfo = true;
}
```

or set the field manually, i.e. not using an automatically implemented-property:

```
private bool retrieveAllInfo = true;
[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool RetrieveAllInfo {
    get {return retrieveAllInfo; }
    set {retrieveAllInfo = value; }
}
```

---

Or, with more recent C# versions (C# 6 or above):

```cs
[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool RetrieveAllInfo { get; set; } = true;
```

Comment: Hello its old question. But is it safe for code generation that use only auto-implemented property now? and remove the retreiveAllInfo field? I mean `public bool RetreiveAllInfo {get;set;} = true` directly? Why I still see most UI libraries use old fashion.

Comment: @KOGRA "yes, that's fine", and "because like this answer: they were written when that syntax didn't exist" (this is the "auto property initializer" feature in C# 6)

Answer (score 0):

One hack for this is on [this](http://www.barsoom.org/defaultvalue-attribute-initial) link.

In short, call this function at the end of constructor.

```
static public void ApplyDefaultValues(object self)
   {
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(self)) {
            DefaultValueAttribute attr = prop.Attributes[typeof(DefaultValueAttribute)] as DefaultValueAttribute;
            if (attr == null) continue;
            prop.SetValue(self, attr.Value);
        }
   }
```

Comment: This is dangerous and shouldn't be used. This sets the properties of derived classes before the base class constructor has finished, before the derived class has had a chance to set up anything needed to make the property setters work.