# NET 6 WebAPI with Swagger - take default value from inline init not from attribute

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Is there a chance to tell swagger to take default value from init not from attribute `[DefaultValue]`?

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public Guid RowId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public int? ExampleInt { get; set; } = 1;
    public string? ExampleText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

I don't want to type all default values twice.

Comment: What library do you use - Swashbuckle, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, NSwag, Swagger-Net, something else?

Comment: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Comment: What effect do you want? Is there anything you want in [this link](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore)?

Comment: The only way to autogenerate default value in swagger ui is to use attribute `[DefaultValue]`, but it has no efect on object so I need to use inline initialization, but then it has no effect on swagger.What I have to do is write both inline init for object and attribute for default value to show up in swagger ui. I don't want to do it twice. It is a waste of time.

Comment: Like all attributes, `[DefaultValue]` is meta data, you must manually set actual default values. Maybe you can only set it twice. Or refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17232853/18789859) to customize the method, but it is dangerous, we do not recommend that you use.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. You might want to share this as additional inference that can be added in [this issue on the ASP.NET repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44232).