# DefaultValue not working as expected when used with Custom Type Convertor

Tags: c#, type-conversion, default-value

Per the below sample code posted I am able to see the values as Risk and Default in the dropdown.

But since I have a setting [DefaultValue("Risk")] above the property named "DummyProperty" I would expect the Risk value selected in the Property Grid Dropdown. But it’s not happening. What am I missing here?

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    string sDummy;

    [DefaultValue("Risk")]
    [Category("Test")]
    [ParamDesc("SystemType")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(PropertyGridTypeConverter))]
    public String DummyProperty
    {
        get { return sDummy; }
        set { sDummy = value; }
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class ParamDesc : Attribute
{
    public ParamDesc(string PD)
    { PropDesc = PD; }

    public string PropDesc 
    { get; set; }

}


class PropertyGridTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            AttributeCollection ua = context.PropertyDescriptor.Attributes;
            ParamDesc cca = (ParamDesc)ua[typeof(ParamDesc)];

            switch (cca.PropDesc)
            {
                case "SystemType":
                    lst = new List<string> {"Risk", "Default"};
                    break;
                case "DateType":
                    lst = new List<string> {"Daily", "Monthly"};
                    break;
            }
        }
        lst.Sort();
        return new StandardValuesCollection(lst);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shuld initialize `sDummy` in constructor. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1980533/2122718

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat confusingly, the DefaultValue custom attribute isn't used to set default values on properties like you want. In fact, it isn't directly used by the runtime at all. It's intended instead for use by the Visual Studio designer.

You'll probably just want to initialize the value elsewhere (such as in the UserControl1 constructor).

More information here:
[.Net DefaultValueAttribute on Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705553/net-defaultvalueattribute-on-properties)