# Set DefaultValueAttribute at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid

Trying to set default values at runtime, the following class is used for my propertygrid:

```
public class zPosition
{
    public int _x;
    public int _y;

    public zPosition(int x, int y, int dx = 0, int dy = 0)
    {
        this._x = 10;
        this._y = 10;
        // set the default values here
    }

    [DisplayName("X"), DefaultValueAttribute(0)]
    public int X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set { _x = value; }
    }

    [DisplayName("Y"), DefaultValueAttribute(0)]
    public int Y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set { _y = value; }
    }

}
```

How would I set those default values in the class constructor?

Thanks

Comment: DefaultValue is only for the designer.  It does not *set* any values.  When the property value matches the DefaultValue attribute value, the designer will not save the information in the Designer file.

Comment: is there a work around to set the default value of a propertygrid property? I need to set them at runtime instead of using the following: DefaultValueAttribute(0)

Comment: How would you use it at runtime?

Comment: You can't do it with the attribute, write private `bool ShouldSerializeXxxx()` and `void ResetXxxx()` methods instead where Xxxx matches the property name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749678/how-to-set-defaultvalueattribute-of-the-propertygrid-dynamically-or-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: `DefaultValueAttribute` cannot be set at runtime. Your understanding of attributes is just wrong.

However, depending on what you really want, there are other possible solutions. See comments and links.